# move/copy constructors combination of multiple parameters

Tags: c++, move-constructor

Let's say I got a class which takes two parameters when constructing. And I need to deal with the rvalue/lvale, does that mean I should write 4 constructors?

```
class Test {
 public:
  Test(const A& a, const B& b) {}
  Test(const A& a, B&& b) {}
  Test(A&& a, const B& b) {}
  Test(A&& a, B&& b) {}
};
```

Is there any way I can do this easier?
Or is this design pattern wrong?

Comment: What do you do with the parameters? Are you copying/moving them to member variables?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat yes.